# Trying to get HttpPost to send two JSON objects to server. Passing 1 object works. 2 does not

Tags: java, android, http, http-post

This is my code that works perfectly to post one object to my server.

```
//Creating HttpPost object
HttpPost post_request = new HttpPost();
//Creating BasicHttpParams
BasicHttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
//Setting parameters to params
params.setParameter("json", j);
//Setting params to post_request
post_request.setParams(params);
//setting HttpPost object URI
post_request.setURI(website);
//executing actual request
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post_request);
```

What I would like to do is to pass two objects as the parameters as so:

```
//Creating HttpPost object
HttpPost post_request = new HttpPost();
//Creating BasicHttpParams
BasicHttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
//Setting parameters to params
params.setParameter("json", j, "json2", j2);
//Setting params to post_request
post_request.setParams(params);
//setting HttpPost object URI
post_request.setURI(website);
//executing actual request
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post_request);
```

Of course, that does not work. I get a red line underneath `setParameter`.

What can I do to pass through two objects in my post? I've read some varying answers like "it's not possible and I would have to import a .jar file", but I feel like there is some easy way I'm missing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
params.setParameter("json", j, "json2", j2);
```

Just call

```
params.setParameter("json", j);
params.setParameter("json2", j2);
```

See the javadoc for what you're calling to understand why this is. http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/params/BasicHttpParams.html

Comment: Logically, shouldn't the second statement override the first?

Comment: The name of the method may be misleading you. `BasicHttpParams` is basically a map from `String`s to `Object`s; it can have more than one parameter. `setParameter` can be thought of as `addOrReplaceParamterWithName`.

Comment: Oh. Thanks! Great response. I appreciate it. Makes sense now that I see the `removeParameter(String name)`.